# Space between divs in a column without affecting height

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have 2 div boxes side by side. I am trying to add a gap of 20px between them.

This is what I am looking to achieve.

[image]

This is what I have now. They are side by side, but stuck to each other.

[image]

If I were to add like 10px margin to right for the first box for example, the 2nd one ends up getting pushed down as follows.

[image]

I tried to wrap them in a div within a div. It works when it comes to getting a gap.

But new problem where previously they were nicely aligned to match the tallest height between the 2 box.

But now it follows the height of the content making them uneven as follows.

[image]

Could I get some help with getting the gap between and still maintain uniform height between the 2 boxes.

This is initial code where the 2 boxes are stuck together.

```
<div className={'row'}>
    <ReactComponentOne>
      className={`${styles.box1} col-md-12 col-lg-6`}
    />
    <ReactComponentTwo>
      className={`${styles.box2} col-md-12 col-lg-6`}
    />
</div>
```

This is where I have the gap between the boxes but the height is mismatched.

```
<div className={'row'}>
    <div className={'col-md-12 col-lg-6'}>
        <ReactComponentOne>
          className={`${styles.box1}`}
        />
    </div>
    <div className={'col-md-12 col-lg-6'}>
        <ReactComponentTwo>
          className={`${styles.box2}`}
        />
    </div>
</div>
```

Styling. Note that I am not using bootstrap here.
Using an internal library but for the above col-* and row classes, the implementation is identical to bootstrap.

```
.box1 {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.box1 {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

How the components uses the className prop.

```
import React from 'react';

const ReactComponentOne = ({className}) => {
  return (
    <div className={className}>
      {/*  other logic */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ReactComponentOne;

import React from 'react';

const ReactComponentTwo = ({className}) => {
  return (
    <div className={className}>
      {/*  other logic */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ReactComponentTwo;
```

Please note that I am not looking to switch to flex / grid.

Trying to stick with the bootstrap grid style to solve this if possible.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with a bit of custom CSS,

Wrap the div1 and div2 inside a parentDiv, and apply the following CSS

```
.parent-div{
  display:flex;
  gap:20px;
}
.div1,.div2{
  flex:1;
  height:100%;
}
```